# How to convert a entry to a string

Tags: python, string, file, tkinter, tkinter-entry

so i'm trying to make my own login page but i'm running into a error when trying to save the user input into the file. i get a error telling me i cant (.write) a Entry it can only do str. how do i convert or make the entry a str?

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()

#if user clicks submit

def reg():
    file = open("login.txt", "a")
    file.write(login)

#display login
myLabel = Label(root, text="login")
myLabel.pack()

#creates a user entry
login = Entry(root, textvariable="login")
login.pack()
#submit buttton
Button(root, text="submit", command=reg).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should remove `textvariable="login"`. `textvariable` is only used when you associate the `Entry` widget with a tkinter variable like `tk.StringVar`.

Answer (score 0):

here I put a example:

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()

#if user clicks submit

def reg():
    value=entry.get() # here you get the string
    print(Value)
    file = open("login.txt", "a")
    file.write(Value)
    file.close()

#display login
myLabel = Label(root, text="login")
myLabel.pack()

#creates a user entry
entry = StringVar()
entryv = Entry(root, textvariable=entry)
entryv.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2,rowspan=1)    
#submit buttton
Button(root, text="submit", command=reg).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: im kinda new to think but if i understand understand correctly, i tried that. it didnt give me a error but also didnt print

Answer (score 0):

You can just call the Entry.get() function to get the internal string

```py
with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(login.get())
```

Comment: idk if i understand 100% but i added .write(login.get()) and it didnt add the input.

Comment: did it have any errors? you can try do to `print(login.get())` and see if it returns the correct string

Answer (score 0):

This code works as expected.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

#if user clicks submit

def reg(var):
    with open("login.txt", "a") as file:
        file.write(var.get())


#display login
myLabel = Label(root, text="login")
myLabel.pack()

#creates a user entry
login_var = StringVar()
entryv = Entry(root, textvariable=login_var).pack()

#submit buttton
Button(root, text="submit", command= lambda: reg(login_var)).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks for the help! i did all that and i got this error " reg() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given"

Comment: @GoToStateFarm Probably, you've missed something. Check now, I've put whole code.

Comment: do u know how i could do that submitting multiple entrys such as username, password and name?

Comment: Simply pass all of them to the `reg()` function using `command` option in submit button. Something like this: `command = lambda: reg(username, password, name)`

Comment: so i tried that and i get a TKinter callback error now...

Comment: def reg(var):
    with open("login.txt", "a") as file:
        file.write(var.get())



#display login
myLabel = Label(root, text="Username")
myLabel.pack()

user_var = StringVar()
entryv = Entry(root, textvariable=user_var).pack()

myLabel = Label(root, text="Password")
myLabel.pack()

pass_var = StringVar()
entryc = Entry(root, textvariable=pass_var).pack()
#submit buttton

Button(root, text="submit", command=lambda: reg(user_var, pass_var)).pack()
Button(root, text="register").pack()

root.mainloop()

Comment: also. how would i make it delete the input after they press submit?